# Social Networking Site in asp.net MVC with Entity Framework code first is better to choose this or another platform? how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to start to develop my own social networking site in asp.net mvc with Entity framework  code frist methodology (linq,back end ms sql server)...is it best choice to select this platform and why?

so, i will start to develop and also any info or link is there please send me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No technology really does provide anything out-of-the-box. You can use MVC with entity framework but also ASP.NET with Linq to SQL (just as an example)

Either way you will have to build it from scratch if you do not want to use external controls. I would strictly recommend telerik ([www.telerik.com](http://www.telerik.com)) They offer great controls for mvc as well as for asp.net. But even if you use external controls you have to design the data/object-structure by yourself

Comment: thanks.. also Mr. Ole i use MVC + 3-tire arch. for my app and as you say i use linq to SQL ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no one true platform that is geared towards writing a social networking web application. Most have their advantages and disadvantages. If you are a .NET developer and you need to build something in RAD then use web forms, if you want to build something with separation and clean code in mind, use MVC.